# Linear Combinations of Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the rows of M are linear combinations of the rows of N. Can someone explain why that means there is a matrix P such that M=PN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rows of M are linear combinations of the rows of N,
then a row of M can be written as a linear equation of a row in N.
This linear equation can be represented in a vector.
The combinations of the vectors which generate the rows of m from the rows in n is called P, where PN = M.