# Linear Combination of the Columns of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain this statement, the linear system **Ax**=**b** has a solution exactly when **b** is a linear combination of the columns of **A**.

Comment: A simpler question: do you know what "linear combination of the columns of $A$" means?

Comment: One of your previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2002799/9464 is related.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the columns of $A$ by $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. If $b$ is a linear combination of these columns, then there exist scalars $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that
$$A_1x_1+\ldots+A_nx_n=b.$$
This is precisely the same as $Ax=b$, where $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a matrix times a vector is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix. Letting $\vec{a}_i$ be the $i^{th}$ column of $A$, we would write this as:

$$A \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{a}_1 & \vec{a}_2 & \cdots & \vec{a}_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} = x_1 \vec{a}_1 + x_2 \vec{a}_2 + \cdots + x_n \vec{a}_n $$

As such, $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ if and only if $x_1 \vec{a}_1 + x_2 \vec{a}_2 + \cdots + x_n \vec{a}_n = \vec{b}$, which is precisely the statement that $\vec{b}$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

For example, the problem

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

has no solutions, since every linear combination of the columns of the matrix must have a 0 in the 3rd component. Equivalently,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 + x_2 \\ x_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's write this linear system (or *system of linear equations*) using matrices. Let $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots& a_{1n}\\ 
a_{21}& a_{22} &\dots & a_{2n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\ a_{n1}& a_{n2}
& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}$. Then the equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ becomes:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots& a_{1n}\\ 
a_{21}& a_{22} &\dots & a_{2n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\ a_{n1}& a_{n2}
& \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now if we compute the matrix multiplication on the left, we get:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n\\
a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dots + a_{2n}x_n\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 + \dots + a_{nn}x_n\\
\end{pmatrix}&= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now we can rewrite the left-hand side of the last equation, using what we know about matrix addition, as follows:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}x_1\\ 
a_{21}x_1\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}x_1
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{12}x_2\\ 
a_{22}x_2\\
\vdots\\
a_{n2}x_2
\end{pmatrix} + \dots + 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1n}x_n\\ 
a_{2n}x_n\\
\vdots\\
a_{nn}x_n
\end{pmatrix}&= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Finally, on the left-hand side we can factor out the scalar $x_i$ in each column, like so:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}\\ 
a_{21}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}
\end{pmatrix}x_1 + 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{12}\\ 
a_{22}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n2}
\end{pmatrix}x_2 + \dots + 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1n}\\ 
a_{2n}\\
\vdots\\
a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}x_n&= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now if you look closely at the above equation, you will notice that it is precisely a *linear combination of the columns of $A$*.